# Problems with color and font size in main.css. How to fix?

Tags: html, css, asp.net

Image version:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExaGb.png

So I am having somes issues with changing the look of my page PrintExtraInfo.aspx.

PrintExtraInfo.aspx:

```
<asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server">
<asp:TableRow>
    <asp:TableCell CssClass="ContactLeftTD">

        <span class="minititle">Auktionsnummer:</span>
        <div class="divider3">
        </div>

        <asp:Label ID="AuctionID1" runat="server"></asp:Label><br />
        <div class="divider3">
        </div>
```

Main.css:

```
.minititle
{
    font-size:20px;
    color:#004c93;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

So whatever color I change it to it stays black. So I have to press F12 (Developer tools in Google Chrome), find the exact place and check the box for color to apply it. Is there any way to fix this?

Also when I change font-size: nothing changes at all, and there is no checkbox or anything for that. Not sure what the problem is since I am fairly new to CSS and apprechiate all the help I can get.

I tried to get all the information needed in my picture at the top for the more visual people here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try giving !important in the color

```
.minititle
{
font-size:20px;
color:#004c93 !important;
font-weight: bold;
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Regards
Maha

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS and HTML look fine to me, perhaps this is a borswer error? Unlickly however.

For the sake of it try changing your `<span>` tags to `<div>` tags and see if it makes any difference>

I just imported your code into fiddle: **http://fiddle.jshell.net/EMJFQ/** and it appeared to come out okay.

Try that, otherwise I really don't know why.